# Хэширование в sha1

Tags: php, md5, sha1

Вообщем,хотел хэшировать пароль под sha1,захэшировал все нормально передается в базу.Только вот у меня проблема с чтением.Тоесть регистрация проводится нормально,хэшированный пароль сохраняется в базу,но только вот как их читать при авторизации?
Вот кусок кода регистрации:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows==0)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO usertbl
        (username, password) 
        VALUES('$username', '$password')";
```

Вот кусок кода авторизации:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']);

$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'");

$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)

{
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername=$row['username'];
$dbpassword=$row['password'];
}

if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
```

Comment: Ну так измените в `SELECT`  `AND password='".$password` на `AND password='".sha1($password)`. Или кто-то вам мешает это сделать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не получается,пишет не правильный пароль.

Comment: @BOPOH, не получается,зашифровал POST(тот что вводится),чтобы при проверке с базой (хэш == хэш) сработал,но нет.

Comment: 1) обновите тогда код вопроса с новыми изменениями 2) покажите в вопросе что подаете на вход при регистрации (`var_dump($_POST['password'], $password)`) и аналогично при логине. Кроме того, покажите что действительно сохранилось в базе для данного пользователя. У вас сейчас, может, опечатка в пароле или логине

Comment: @Ersultan Может вы когда пароль 1-й раз вводили или второй там какие-нибудь пробелы были и вы их не обрезали. А может и правда пароль неправильный. Попробуйте сделать пароль для начала `1`. И на нем проверяйте. Вобще попробуте до `SELECT` вывести `echo sha1($password). " - " .$password;` Посмотреть что реально ввели

Comment: @ВОРОН, обновил

Comment: SHA1 - не шифрование.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов,Изменил,ошибся.

Comment: SHA1 [уже не считается криптографически устойчивым](https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это один из тех вопросов, на который отвечать буквально нет смысла.
Поскольку буквальный ответ будет очевидным, а вот предпосылки к вопросу - неправильными.

1. sha1 стоит на грани небезопасности. Для хеширования паролей в РНР следует применять [специально предназначенные для этого функции.](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.passwords.php)
2. **Переменные никогда нельзя подставлять SQL запрос напрямую**, а только передавать через псевдопеременные - плейсхолдеры. Хотя такой подход и можно реализовать на базе функций mysql, но во-первых, для этого надо писать специальную библиотеку, а во-вторых, эти функции уже удалены их РНР. Поэтому наиболее распространенным выбором будет использование функций [PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo)

Таким образом, код регистрации будет выглядеть примерно так

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM usertbl WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
if($stmt->fetchColumn())
{
    $hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usertbl (username, password) VALUES(?,?)";
    $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$_POST['username'], $hash])
}
```

а код проверки - такой:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username=?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']))
{
```